# Deleting specific rows with VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro for pasting in tab delimited data and adding color codes based on the last column. I the issue is that I'm trying to condense the data by deleting rows that have the last column as 1-5. However the line in under this conditional doesn't do anything. I have confirmed it is running on the correct rows using msgbox. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x, rowStart, colStart As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)

    colStart = rng.Column
    rowStart = rng.Row

rng.PasteSpecial

Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

For x = (rowStart + 1) To (rowStart + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) - 1)
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) = "0" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13)).Style = "Good"
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) > 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) < 6 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13)).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) = "6" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) = "7" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13)).Style = "Neutral"
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) > 7 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13)).Style = "Bad"
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) = "-" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 12)).Style = "Normal"
    End If

Next

ActiveSheet.Cells(rowStart, colStart).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
End With

ActiveSheet.Cells(rowStart, colStart + 4).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End With

ActiveSheet.Cells(rowStart, colStart).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you delete the 2nd row, the next `x` value is going to be 3. Meanwhile the rest of your data is going to move up one row.  The next row is going to get skipped over because even thought you'll want to evaluate what was originally the 3rd row, it is now taking place of the deleted 2nd row.

```
row 1 a
row 2 b <---meets condition, delete , x = 2
row 3 c
row 4 d
```

next x

```
row 1 a
row 2 c <--skipped
row 3 d <--next iteration, x = 3
```

the solution is to put in a line after you delete that decrements x

```
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) > 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) < 6 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13)).EntireRow.Delete
    x = x - 1
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) = "6" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13) = "7" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart), ActiveSheet.Cells(x, colStart + 13)).Style = "Neutral"
ElseIf
```

A better solution would be to use a while loop so you don't have to iterate over any blank rows at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting or adding rows, you should always loop backwards to avoid skipping rows.

Change your loop declaration to this:

```
For x = (rowStart + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) - 1) To rowStart + 1) Step -1
```

This tells the code to start from the bottom and loop backwards up to the top. This will make sure all the rows are deleted as required.

Try the following code instead:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection

rng.PasteSpecial

rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

For x = (rowStart + WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) - 1) To (rowStart + 1) Step -1
    Select Case Cells(x, rng.Column + 13).value
        Case "0": Range(Cells(x, rng.Column), Cells(x, rng.Column + 13)).Style = "Good"
        Case 1 To 5: Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
        Case 6, 7: Range(Cells(x, rng.Column), Cells(x, eng.Column + 13)).Style = "Neutral"
        Case Is > 7: Range(Cells(x, rng.Column), Cells(x, eng.Column + 13)).Style = "Bad"
        Case "-": Range(Cells(x, rng.Column), Cells(x, eng.Column + 13)).Style = "Normal"
    End Select
Next

With rng.CurrentRegion.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
End With

With rng
    Range(Cells(.Row, .Column + 4), .Cells(.Cells.count)).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```